# ruby on rails mac os x console interpreter problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, console, interpreter

just installed ruby on rails last ver on mac os x snow leopard, the ruby interpreter is not working in console, ex if i type : ruby filex.rb nothing happens (no output at all) ... if i press ruby also nothing happens, but the irb command works if i type irb filex.rb

how to fix that... ? installed directly , not with macports...

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `which ruby` see if you are getting anything. But it seems like the ruby binary is not linked in properly.

You can try to link it yourself if you know where the ruby installed to

```
ln -s /usr/bin/ruby /path/to/ruby/installation/ruby
```

*The paths may vary from system to system, so this might not be 100% correct everywhere

Comment: done but it is not working, iv also copied the ruby file from my install dir to /usr/bin/ruby ....

Comment: Hmm, if you can find the location of your irb, that might be where the working ruby is located, then you can try to symlink that one. Unless that is the ruby in question?

Comment: Another option, though it leaves this problem still open, would be to use RVM. Little more to learn, but RVM will make managing Ruby installations a bit easier.

Comment: reinstallied it ... here what shows the installer (after sudo make install) :
nstalling binary commands:   /usr/bin
installing base libraries:    /usr/lib
installing arch files:        /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-darwin10.7.0
installing extension objects: /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-darwin10.7.0
installing extension objects: /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/i386-darwin10.7.0
installing extension objects: /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/i386-darwin10.7.0